Right-click on Desktop does not raise context menu on remote Windows 10 after Windows Update?
I usually use remmina on Linux to connect to a Windows 10 desktop machine over RDP:
C:\WINDOWS\system32>systeminfo

OS Name:                   Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise
OS Version:                10.0.19045 N/A Build 19045

Yesterday, things worked, in the sense that when I right-clicked on an empty area of the Desktop, the usual context menu got raised.
Today, I installed Windows Updates - and I started having a problem with right-click context menu on the Desktop.
EDIT: I just confirmed that this problem does not occur with the Windows 10 Remote Desktop Connection client - so I guess it's time to file a bug with remmina; here it is issue #3211
Apparently the updates were these:
PS C:\tmp> Get-WUHistory -MaxDate (Get-Date).AddDays(-1) | Select Operationname,Result,Date,Title | ConvertTo-Csv
#TYPE Selected.System.__ComObject
"OperationName","Result","Date","Title"
"Installation","Succeeded","2024-10-10 10:52:34 AM","Security Intelligence Update for Microsoft Defender Antivirus - KB2267602 (Version 1.419.433.0) - Current Channel (Broad)"
"Installation","Succeeded","2024-10-10 10:52:14 AM","Security Intelligence Update for Microsoft Defender Antivirus - KB2267602 (Version 1.419.428.0) - Current Channel (Broad)"
"Installation","Succeeded","2024-10-10 10:20:42 AM","Security Intelligence Update for Microsoft Defender Antivirus - KB2267602 (Version 1.419.422.0) - Current Channel (Broad)"
"Installation","Succeeded","2024-10-10 10:20:29 AM","2024-10 Cumulative Update for Windows 10 Version 22H2 for x64-based Systems (KB5044273)"
"Installation","Succeeded","2024-10-10 10:09:40 AM","2024-10 Security Update for Windows 10 Version 22H2 for x64-based Systems (KB5046400)"
"Installation","Succeeded","2024-10-10 10:07:41 AM","2024-10 Cumulative Update for .NET Framework 3.5, 4.8 and 4.8.1 for Windows 10 Version 22H2 for x64 (KB5044091)"
"Installation","Succeeded","2024-10-10 10:07:05 AM","Windows Malicious Software Removal Tool x64 - v5.129 (KB890830)"

... and now I experience this:

If I access that Windows machine right after reboot with VNC, right-click context menu on Desktop works (context menu is raised/shown)

Also on the local machine with physically attached mouse, after reboot right-click context menu on Desktop works


If I afterwards close VNC, and gain access with remmina, when I right-click on the Desktop, nothing happens (that is, the context menu is not shown anymore) - however, right-click within any other software works as usual; and even in File Explorer, the right-click still works (and raises the usual context menu, the one I usually get when I right-click on the desktop)

Actually, it turns out also the icons are not clickable on the Desktop (anymore?)
If I open File Explorer and go to Desktop, I can select/double-click icons from there at first; but if I then try right-click there, it will not be raised - and after that the icons in there freeze too (cannot be clicked or double-clicked)
Folders other than Desktop leave the right-click context menu working in File Explorer
Also on the local machine with physically attached mouse, right-click context menu on Desktop remains non-working after it stopped working with remmina


If I afterwards close remmina, and again gain access with VNC, the problem persists: that is, when I right-click an empty area of the Desktop, no context menu is shown (nothing happens), while right-click in any other software still works

I have tried:

Restarting Windows Explorer from Task Manager

Restarting Desktop Window Manager as per https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/kuy66m/desktop_window_manager_ate_6gb_of_ram_how_to/
 taskkill /F /IM dwm.exe
 taskkill /F /IM conhost.exe



... none of this worked to bring the right-click context menu on Desktop back.
What can I do to debug this issue - and to hopefully fix it?

related: python script to inspect mouse events on Windows: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56079533/windows-10-mouse-touchscreen-event-log

I assume you have tried a system reboot?

@Ramhound - I sure did, it even says "If I access that Windows machine right after reboot" in the OP

That suggests something that is automatically started is causing this problem. If you use AutoRuns to disable all nonessential software does the behavior change?
